# Sorcerer Wild Surge result quandries

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, targeting, duration, wild-magic

I've got a couple of questions about some of the results in the wild surge table for the sorcerer.

First of all, the magic missile result. On a roll of 09-10 "You cast *magic missile* as a 5th-level spell." Who is the target of the magic missiles? For most of the other surges that have a spell effect it states that it's centered or targeted on "yourself" (the caster). In fact, the only other spell result I can see that doesn't list a target is the *mirror image* result, and that spell is range of self, so it's kind of obvious who the target is.

Possible targets for the magic missile:

- Sorcerer chooses target of each missile (all one target or each to separate targets)
- Single Target is chosen randomly (DM or player rolls to determine)
- Each missile targets a randomly chosen target (DM or player rolls to determine)
- Sorcerer is automatically targeted

Secondly, the size change surge result doesn't seem to have a time limit on it. This implies that the size change is permanent. I'm not sure if this is the intended effect. Although, it does lead to some interesting roleplaying as a sorcerer could theoretically be increased or decreased by a full size category (or more) over a course of their career if they happen to roll this same result enough times, and then roll high enough on the size change die.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The table has a few very specific verbiages and they indicate how the effect happens:

- Controlled by the DM. This is what it means, a monster controlled by the DM appears
- You cast X centered on yourself. This means you cast a spell with the center point of the area of effect being yourself.
- You cast X spell. This means you cast the spell being in full control of the targeting.
- You cast X on yourself. The spell affects you, and you only.
- You cast X on a random creature. A random creature is chosen from the valid targets.
- As far as the size change, it says "for the next minute". With the height change one, you're just as likely to shrink, and you'd have to grow (or shrink) several times (like 10ish?) without a corresponding shrink roll to actually change size categories.

Wild magic is supposed to be unpredictable, that means sometimes you get to control the targetting, sometimes you don't Specifically with Magic Missile and the result where up to 3 creatures get lightning damage, the sorcerer is *in control*.